# How to retrieve all apps belonging to a business with Facebook Graph API v2.12?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

(the illustrating code is written in Python. I guess, it's self-explanatory. The question aims at the respective HTTP GET request.)

This works with API v2.10:

```
import requests

req = requests.request(
    "GET",
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/"+str(business_id)+"/apps",
    params={
        "access_token": access_token
    }
)
```

result with `req.json()`:

```
{'data': [{'access_status': 'CONFIRMED',
   'access_type': 'OWNER',
   'id': '19...30',
   'name': 'example.org',
   'permitted_access_types': ['CAN_ADVERTISE_APP'],
   'permitted_roles': ['ADMINISTRATOR',
    'DEVELOPER',
    'TESTER',
    'INSIGHTS_USER',
    'TEST_USER']},
   ...
]}
```

That's great - but the same request to the most recent API version (2.12):

```
req = requests.request(
    "GET",
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/"+str(business_id)+"/apps",
    params={
        "access_token": access_token
    }
)
```

yields a deprecation error:

```
{'error': {'code': 12,
  'fbtrace_id': 'A...PZ',
  'message': '(#12) apps field is deprecated for versions v2.11 and higher',
  'type': 'OAuthException'}}
```

How do I have to rephrase the request for v2.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#mapi-new-BM

> To access business apps:
>
> `BUSINESS_ID/owned_apps` - To get a list of apps the business owns
>   `BUSINESS_ID/client_apps` - To get a list of apps of the clients of the business
>   `BUSINESS_ID/pending_client_apps` - To get a list of apps belonging to clients of a business that are pending approval

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/connectionobjects/v2.12#app

> You can list all apps for a specific business manager that you can advertise for. Query the business's owned_apps edge with an access token with ads_management permissions:
>
> ```
> curl -G \
> -d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
> "https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/owned_apps"
> ```